# Google Tag Manager - Custom HTML Tag that sets/resets cookies - Creating an event to track user navigation

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I recently thought of a scenario and a solution for tracking user behavior with Google Tag Manager (GTM) and Google Analytics (GA).  I wanted to get some feedback on the idea from other GTM and GA users in the community.

Scenario:
There may be an individual or company, who would like to know when a user completed a specified conversion path on their website; perhaps, they wanted to know which users visited a product description page, education page, and, then visited the store page, in that exact order.

There are many ways to capture that behavior.  The solution that seemed best to me was to send a Custom Event (ex: "Path Complete") to GA by doing the following in GTM:

1 - Create a Custom HTML Tag in GTM that uses JavaScript to set/reset a tracking cookie on every PageView.  This will read/increment/reset the cookie based on the built-in Page URL variable.  The cookie value will increase with each step of the goal.

2 - Create a Custom JavaScript Variable to read the cookie value during every event.

3 - Create a Tag/Trigger in GTM that sends an Event when the user has performed the final step.  The condition would be, for example, cookieValue=2 and store page link clicked.

This was shown to work on my own end.  I was able to view the "Path Complete" in Google Analytics after testing and publishing the solution above.

Does anyone feel that this a bad way to do things or that there may be a more effective solution to the problem?  Is it typically a bad practice to create Custom HTML tags that set/reset cookies?

Comment: The better way would be to use a custom template (e.g. https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/GrowthSavvy/templates/CustomCookieTag) instead of custom html. Within the EU writing cookies requires use consent.